# Куда сохраняется значение из input на html странице если не в атрибут value?

Tags: html, input, selenium

Есть страница https://www.anibis.ch/de/login.aspx

Если вписать в поле логина какой-то текст, то сам хтмл не меняется:

```
<input type="text" required="" autofocus="autofocus" class="text" tabindex="1" id="ctl00_phlContent_ctlLogin_txtUsername" name="ctl00$phlContent$ctlLogin$txtUsername">
```

то есть нету атрибута value как такового. Но в то же время само значение куда-то сохраняется. Мне нужен способ его достать програмно с помощью джава-скрипта или Selenium web-driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аттрибута `value` просто не видно. Если ты данного элемента взять аттрибут `value`, то вернется как раз значение, которое записано в данном `input`

В хроме так находит :

```
$x('.//input[contains(@id,"Login") and contains(@id,"Username")]')[0].value
```

Код на java :

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpaht(".//input[contains(@id,'Login') and contains(@id,'Username')]"));
String atr = element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: довольно странно, но у меня не находит. В таком случае встает вопрос: Нужно ли обновлять(заново находить) елемент после ввода текста?

Comment: А что он тебе пустую строку возвращает? Попробуй переискать элемент

Comment: Похоже что у меня проблема в другом месте кода... Спасибо за ответ...